# The equation of a plane passing through three noncolinear points $p_1 = (x_1 , y_1 , z_1)$, $p_2 = (x_2 , y_2 , z_2)$, $p_3 = (x_3 , y_3 , z_3)$

Tags: vectors, affine-geometry, solid-geometry

Show that an equation of a plane passing through three noncolinear points
$p_1 = (x_1 , y_1 , z_1)$, $p_2 = (x_2 , y_2 , z_2)$, $p_3 = (x_3 , y_3 , z_3)$ is given by $(p − p_1) \times (p − p_2) \cdot (p − p_3) = 0$,
where $p = (x, y, z)$ is an arbitrary point of the plane and $p − p_1$, for
instance, means the vector $(x − x_1 , y − y_1 , z − z_1)$.

I have the following reasoning:

"Explicitly, the plane $\mathcal{P}$ through the point $P_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is uniquely determined (up to a scalar multiple) by a normal vector $\mathbf n = \langle a,b,c \rangle$ according to the following: a point $P$ lies on $\mathcal{P}$ if and only if $\mathbf n$ and $\overrightarrow{P_0 P}$ are orthogonal if and only if $n \cdot \overrightarrow{P_0 P} = 0$ if and only if $$a(x - x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z - z_0) = 0.$$ By setting $d = ax_0 + by_0 + cz_0,$ we have $ax + by + cz = d.$"

But I have not been able to finish the problem because I must get the equation of the plane of the form $(p − p_1) \times (p − p_2) \cdot (p − p_3) = 0$. I need help to do this.

Comment: The equation is not linear. Should be $p_3-$ instead of the first two $p-$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noticed, we should have a $p_3$ instead of a $p$ for the cross product used to determine the normal, then we can use the [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) determinant

$$\left[(p_3 − p_1) \times (p_3 − p_2)\right] \cdot (p − p_3)=\det \begin{vmatrix}x_3-x_1&y_3-y_1&z_3-z_1\\x_3-x_2&y_3-y_2&z_3-z_2\\x-x_3&y-y_3&z-z_3 \end{vmatrix}=0$$

to get the plane equation.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I should prove. Really what I should get is the equation of the plane of the form $(p-p_1) \times (p-p_2)  \cdot (p-p_3) =0$

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh It is uncorrect. Normal vector is given by $N=(p_3 − p_1) \times (p_3 − p_2)$ and for any point $p$ in the plane we have $N\cdot (p-p_3)=0$ that is $$[(p_3 − p_1) \times (p_3 − p_2)] \cdot (p − p_3)$$ Of course we can use any permuation of the three points for $N$ and any $N\cdot (p-p_i)$ for the equation.

Comment: Now I understand, but I have two questions: Is it necessary to show that the normal vector is $ N = (p_3 − p_1) × (p_3 − p_2) $.

Comment: On the other hand, with the answer you gave above, is it sufficient for the exercise test, that is, when I consider the determinant of the expression $ \left [(p_3 - p_1) \times (p_3 - p_2) \right] \cdot (p - p_3) $ is the equation of the plane derived?

Comment: In other words, I don't understand how to deduce the equation of the plane from $$ \left [(p_3 - p_1) \times (p_3 - p_2) \right] \cdot (p - p_3) = \det \begin {vmatrix} x_3-x_1 & y_3-y_1 & z_3-z_1 \\ x_3-x_2 & y_3-y_2 & z_3-z_2 \\ x-x_3 & y-y_3 & z-z_3 \end {vmatrix} = 0 $$

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh The formula $N = (p_3 − p_1) × (p_3 − p_2)$ is justified by the definition of cross product since $v=u \times w$ is orthogonal to $u$ and $w$.

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh Yes it works and we just need to apply the formula for the determinant? Aren't you aware about that? As an alternative we can first find N and then determine $N\cdot (p-p_i)$.

Comment: OK. now everything is clearer, thank you very much.

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh You are welcome! Bye